# The number of Banach spaces on $\mathbb{R} $

Tags: metric-spaces

How many possible Banach spaces are there on the entire set $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Thanks

Comment: How you mean how many? Are you interested in non isometrics one? Because there should be infinite many different banachspaces on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: It depends on what you mean by different. For any $c>0$, the norm $\|x\|_c = c |x|$ is a different norm, and $(\mathbb{R}, \|\cdot \|_c)$ is a Banach space.

Comment: You don't really need the emphasis that "on the entire set ${\mathbb R}$" provides. Since a Banach space is also a vector space (over ${\mathbb R},$ in this case), the question obviously doesn't arise for a proper subset of ${\mathbb R}.$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant upto isomorphism, there is exactly one, since all norms on $\mathbb{R}$ are equivalent. ( in fact, any norm on $\mathbb{R}$ looks like $c|x|$) (Your  [definition](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Banach%20space#maps_between_banach_spaces_11)  of isomorphism doesn't matter in this case)